# Dynamic routing for approval process for multiple approvers.

Tags: approval-process

I have a custom object "Subject" and related object professors. For example, Math is a subject record and there are multiple professor records for MATH. Professor record has a pick list primary reviewer and secondary reviewer.

I need to write an approval process on a custom object application . Once the application submitted, based on subject and other information on subject object record , I need to find primary and secondary reviewers .There wil be muitple primary and secondary approvers.

Please help to design approval process for there.There are more than 100 subjects .  Thanks a lots

Comment: Can some help me with this approval process. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. 
http://appirio.com/category/tech-blog/2015/06/dynamic-approval-routing-in-salesforce/

dynamic selection of multiple approvers at each step

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please add a few more sentences about the content of your link. Links might break, rendering your answer worthless then...